# Can't Install Topojson

Tags: node.js, homebrew, topojson

When installing topojson from npm (which I installed through homebrew)I get the following:

```
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/MuhammadShaaban/package.json'
npm WARN MuhammadShaaban No description
npm WARN MuhammadShaaban No repository field.
npm WARN MuhammadShaaban No README data
npm WARN MuhammadShaaban No license field.
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.3.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "topojson"
npm ERR! node v7.3.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path /Users/MuhammadShaaban/node_modules/topojson/node_modules/topojson-server/bin/geo2topo
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall chmod

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/Users/MuhammadShaaban/node_modules/topojson/node_modules/topojson-server/bin/geo2topo'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/Users/MuhammadShaaban/node_modules/topojson/node_modules/topojson-server/bin/geo2topo'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/MuhammadShaaban/npm-debug.log
```

I have looked through other similar type questions but cant find a fix. Any idea on how to correct this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `npm install topojson --no-bin-links`